# How do i make changes of one dropdownlist reflect on other dropdown list in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdownlistfor

I have two dropdown lists. One is showing **emp_id** , while the other is showing **emp_name**. 
Both lists use the same sql data source which queries as : 
*select emp_id , emp-name from emp_table*

How do i make changes of one dropdownlist reflect on other?

Say, **if i select emp-id, then corresponding emp_name should be selected automatically and vice versa**. How can we do that?
I have used SqlDataSource from toolbox and have not configured it manually through code. I am passing a stored procedure which returns emp_name and emp_id from emp_table.

This is simple asp.net project and no mvc has been used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this setup:

1. Use the emp_id as the **value** for both drop downs.
2. Add a `SelectedIndexChange` event handler for both drop downs. In the event handler, get the emp_id value and set the selected value of the other drop down to the same emp_id.
3. Set properties `Autopostback=true` and `CausesValidation=false` for both drop down.

Answer (score 2):

Below are the steps:

1. Bind both dropdown with value = emp_id and text = emp_name
2. onchange event of dropdown1, call a javascript function having below code
   $('#dropdown2').val($('#dropdown2').val());